# Magento 2 Add to cart API covert quote

Tags: magento2

I am creating Add to cart API and is working fine with logged-in customer but I have following **query**:

**Query:-** Suppose as a guest I have added product to cart and now I am login then how to convert guest quote to customer quote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new merge cart API for this.

**webapi.xml**

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
<route url="/V1/mergeGuestCart" method="POST">
    <service class="WebbyTroops\MergeGuestCart\Api\MergeGuestCartInterface" method="mergeCart"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data> 
</route> 
</routes>
```

**MergeCartInterface.php**

```
namespace WebbyTroops\MergeGuestCart\Api;

/**
 * Interface MergeGuestCartInterface
 * @package WebbyTroops\MergeGuestCart\Api
 */
interface MergeGuestCartInterface
{

    /**
     * Merge guest cart to logged in customer cart
     *
     * @param string $guestQuoteId
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function mergeCart($guestQuoteId, $customerId);
}
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="WebbyTroops\MergeGuestCart\Api\MergeGuestCartInterface" type="WebbyTroops\MergeGuestCart\Model\MergeGuestCart" />
</config>
```

**MergeCart.php**

```
namespace WebbyTroops\MergeGuestCart\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\SaveHandler;

class MergeGuestCart implements \WebbyTroops\MergeGuestCart\Api\MergeGuestCartInterface
{

public function __construct(
    CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
    QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
    QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    SaveHandler $saveHandler
) {
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
    $this->quoteFactory=$quoteFactory;
    $this->saveHandler = $saveHandler;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function mergeCart($guestQuoteId, $customerId){
    $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($guestQuoteId, 'masked_id');
    $guestQuote= $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId());
    $quote= $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerId);

    if($quote->merge($guestQuote)){
        try{
            $this->saveHandler->save($quote);
            $quote->collectTotals();
            return true;
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Once you add product to guest cart you will get quote mask id otherwise you can get this from quote_id_mast. You can test this in any REST client like postman. Request payload will be like

```
{
  "guest_quote_id" : "z7sMMVNXpEFFOGXM9A6zt5RijsM39dKE"
}
```

with endpoint(POST) as

```
http://magento/rest/V1/mergeGuestCart
```

Make sure you are sending customer token in header. Let me know if need further help.

Comment: thanks for update, is there any default magenro 2 API to merge guest quote with customer quote ?

Comment: there is no default API for merge cart

Comment: Did it work for you? if yes then please accept this answer. it'll help others

Comment: I am implementing i will accept answer once it complete and working.

Comment: SaveHandler is not work with API, bcoz SaveHandler is using Session.

Comment: Is it throwing any error?

Comment: Actully Session is not working in API so it throw exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85122/discussion-between-ramkishan-and-niranjan-gondaliya).

Comment: I get  "message": "Request does not match any route.", this error when I post this /rest/V1/mergeGuestCart when I use this json in body    {
 "guest_quote_id":"78ca722b0d2b30b13a36d779e74f2634" 

}

Comment: how can I send customer token on header ? Give me an example