# How to merge guest cart product into active customer cart using REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I need to merge the guest cart items into customer active cart using end point API but as per my code its throwing the following error.

```
Array
(
    [message] => Cannot assign customer to the given cart. Customer already has active cart.
)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
$adminUrl1='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token';
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    $data1 = array("username" => 'abc@gmail', "password" => 'Oditek123@');
    $data_string1 = json_encode($data1);                       
    $ch1 = curl_init($adminUrl1); 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string1);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string1))                                                                       
    );       
    $token1 = curl_exec($ch1);

$quoteUrl ='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/z5546670365f8d78882b03ea9b1f8e08';
    $data_string2=array("customerId"=>84,"storeId"=>1);
    $chQuote = curl_init($quoteUrl);
    curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); 
    curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data_string2));
    curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token1)));
    curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $array = json_decode(curl_exec($chQuote),TRUE);
    print_r($array);exit;
```

Here I need to transfer all guest cart items into customer active cart after customer login. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: There is no default merge cart API. You can try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248287/magento-2-add-to-cart-api-covert-quote/248335#248335

Comment: I am using only end point for mobile app so how I will use those extensions.

Comment: did you find the solutions for this error..?
I also want to merge guest cart item to login user by rest api.